# Vaadin EntityManager - createQuery don't work ?

Tags: java, spring, gwt, vaadin

Hi everybody so I’m doing my first steps in Vaadin / GWT and I found that maybe I don’t get some mechanics that’s its ruled or something else. First of all my modifications are done on dashboard-demo you can check this out here -> https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo

I'm trying to get some data from my database. I used JPA a lot in spring projects so I configured all propertly but just to be sure here is my persistance.xml:

> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
>                version="2.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="transactionUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>


    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I also have some ultra easy User classes:

```
@Entity(name = "USERS")
public class UserImpl implements User, java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7872836283108223143L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true)
    protected String username;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    protected String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    protected String lastName;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    protected String email;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    protected String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    protected String password;

    @Column(name = "ENABLED")
    protected boolean active;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


}
```

And going to point I have such method (also UBER easy):

```
@Subscribe

public void userLoginRequested(final UserLoginRequestedEvent event) {

EntityManager em = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("transactionUnit")
        .createEntityManager();

TypedQuery<com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.domain.classes.UserImpl> query = em.createQuery("SELECT user FROM com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.domain.classes.UserImpl user WHERE LOWER(username) = :username", com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.domain.classes.UserImpl.class);
com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.domain.classes.UserImpl testUser;

testUser = query.getSingleResult();

User user = getDataProvider().authenticate(event.getUserName(),
        event.getPassword());
VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute(User.class.getName(), user);;
```

}

Method should simple return object but no I have such error:

> [EL Info]: 2015-11-24
>   15:43:16.62--ServerSession(1650623529)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913 [EL Info]: 2015-11-24
>   15:43:16.797--ServerSession(1650623529)--file:/D:/Serwery/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/_transactionUnit
>   login successful lis 24, 2015 3:43:16 PM
>   com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault SEVERE: 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;
>     at
>   com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.DashboardUI.userLoginRequested(DashboardUI.java:103)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
>     at
>   com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
>     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
>     at
>   com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
>     at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)  at
>   com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.event.DashboardEventBus.post(DashboardEventBus.java:17)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.demo.dashboard.view.LoginView$1.buttonClick(LoginView.java:102)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
>     at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)     at
>   com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)  at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1003)
>     at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)  at
>   com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:61)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:313)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:202)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
>     at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:351)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Question is what is wrong with my approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the right java persistence version in your class path?

The `createQuery` method you try to calling is first available since version 2.0

```
/**
* @since Java Persistence 2.0
*/
public <T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery);
```

If you using maven, do it like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Not like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```